# Losing redux state between page changes

Tags: reactjs, redux

In my app, I dispatch an array of playlists to my redux store in my Dashboard component like this

```
render() {
    this.getPlaylists();
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Dashboard</h1>
            <Playlists playlists={this.state.playlists}/>
            <button onClick={this.handleOnClick}><a>Let's start!</a></button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

and the handleOnClick simply calls the dispatch function.

Afterwards, I check my redux store to see if the playlists truly are in there, and they are. However, when I go to a new route and get the state info inside the redux store, everything is set back to default value, even though I checked that the array was in the store prior to switching pages. Does anyone have any idea why this is?

EDIT:
Here is my reducer

```
const playlistReducerDefaultState = {
    playlists: []
};

export default function(state = playlistReducerDefaultState, action) {
    console.log('reducer state', action);
    switch (action.type) {  
        case 'PLACE_PLAYLISTS':
            return {
                playlists: action.playlists
            }
        default:
            return state;
    };
};
```

EDIT: Here is code for the Dashboard component

```
const spotifyapi = new SpotifyWebApi();

class Dashboard extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleOnClick = this.handleOnClick.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            playlists: []
        };
    }

async getPlaylists() {
    if (this.props.auth.user) {
        spotifyapi.setAccessToken(this.props.auth.user.accessToken);
        const playlists = await spotifyapi.getUserPlaylists(this.props.auth.user.spotifyId);
        this.setState(() => {
            return {
                playlists: playlists.items
            }
        })
    }
}

handleOnClick(e) {
    console.log('current props: ', this.props);
    this.props.dispatch(placePlaylists(this.state.playlists));
}

render() {
    this.getPlaylists();
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Dashboard</h1>
            <Playlists playlists={this.state.playlists}/>
            <button onClick={this.handleOnClick}><a>Let's start!</a></button>
        </div>
        );
    }
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        auth: state.auth,
        playlists: state.playlists
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Dashboard);
```

Additionally, here is my router

```
return (
        <div>
            <BrowserRouter>
                <div>
                    <Header />
                    <Route exact path="/" component={Landing} />
                    <Route path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard}/>
                    <Route path="/active" component={Active}/>
                </div>
            </BrowserRouter>
        </div>
    )
```

My component gathers playlist data in the Dashboard and puts that data into the store. However, when I go to the /active route, that data disappears. A commenter said that the redux state does not persist across page loads. How do I go from one route to another without a new page load?

Comment: Could you upload your reducer? You need to make sure you are returning the new state.

Comment: Just added the reducer!

Comment: Could you please provide all of your React component code, including the code for `this.handleOnClick`?

Comment: Redux does not persist the state of your application between page reloads. You can take a look at redux-persist for that. Essentially, it serializes your page state whenever it changes and re-hydrates your store upon page load. This is not the default behavior. You may get around this by using a routing library such as react-router instead of hard page reloads.

Comment: Added code for the component and for my router

Comment: How do you navigate between routes in your app? If you're doing normal `<a href="/dashboard">DashBoard</a>` you're going to have a sad time, use `<Link>` from react-router package to do the navigating for you as it takes care of pushing state and replacing state properly.

Comment: Ah yes! I forgot about <Link>! That has to be the bug. Thank you so much!

Comment: One more question: If a user manually decides to type in the route in the search bar instead of using the <Link>, will the redux data not persist? Do they have to use <Link> to navigate between routes?